# How to calculate the distance between a document and each centroid (k-means)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I executed scikit-learn k-means algorithm and got the resulting centroids. I have a new document (was not in the initial collection) and I would like to calculate the distance between every centroid and the new document to know in which cluster it should be placed.

Is there a built in function to achieve that or should I write a similarity function manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method [`predict`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans.predict) to get the closest cluster for each sample in a matrix `X`:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

model = KMeans(n_clusters=K)
model.fit(X_train)
label = model.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: I have another question, X_test sparse matrix should have the same dimensionality than X_train? I ask this, because I'm using TF-IDF normalization, so I have to take into account the X_train features to generate the X_test matrix

Comment: It should have the same number of features but not necessarily the same number of samples.

Comment: I see. So I will have to add the new sample to the initial dictionary, use vectorizer.fit_transform() again and then pass only the desired row to the predict method right?

Comment: I think you just have to use the transform method of your vectorizer. Else, you would change the transform and tuhs the input space and your clustering will be off. So you can either use the `vectorizer` on `X_train+X_test` before using the `fit` method of `KMeans` or avoid only fit the `vectorizer` on `X_train`.

Comment: Yeah, I think the second option is better, because if I use the vectorizer on X_train + X_test, the clustering would be performed taking into account the document that I want to predict. Thank you very much for your help.